# React Navigation npm install ERR fresh Expo Init @react-navigation/native@3.1.4

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native, react-navigation, expo

React Native Expo Users!

I am running into error on expo init with react-navigation (both blank & with tabs):

```
npm ERR! 404  '@react-navigation/native@3.1.4' is not in the npm registry.
```

I have been developing with React Native using Expo for several months now and have great success learning and solving errors along the way!

I took a holiday, came back to start a new project, and hit a wall with react-navigation@^3.0.0 - I have tried many solutions and nonwork.

I am using expo and npm to start a new project, both tabs and blank template have the react-navigation npm install issue:

```
expo init
? Choose a template: expo-template-tabs
? Choose which workflow to use: managed
✔ Please enter a few initial configuration values.
  Read more: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration · 100% completed
? Yarn v1.13.0 found. Use Yarn to install dependencies? No
[08:18:30] Extracting project files...
[08:18:31] Customizing project...
[08:18:31] Initialized a git repository.
[08:18:31] Installing dependencies...
npm WARN deprecated kleur@2.0.2: Please upgrade to kleur@3 or migrate to 'ansi-colors' if you prefer the old syntax. Visit <https://github.com/lukeed/kleur/releases/tag/v3.0.0\> for migration path(s).
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@react-navigation%2fnative - Not Found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@react-navigation/native@3.1.4' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 Your package name is not valid, because
npm ERR! 404  1. name can only contain URL-friendly characters
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'react-navigation'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ddcjosiahl/.npm/_logs/2019-02-08T13_18_47_333Z-debug.log
[08:18:47] Process exited with non-zero code: 1
[08:18:47] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

I am trying options with no luck:

- Cleared NPM cache
- Tried Yarn
- Install expo cli again
- npm install --save react-navigation ... react-native, native, etc

  npm install --save react-navigation
  npm ERR! code E404
  npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @react-navigation/native@3.1.4

  - **Note:** I have spent all day yesterday trying to get new projects to work. I did manage to get passed it by installing different versions of react-native, and cannot replicate...which then caused a mismatch of versions and app wouldn't load:*

****RNGestureHandlerButton:****
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRBXc.jpg)

**Why is react-navigation@^3.0.0 needing native@3.1.4 and how to solve?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue while upgrading from expo v31 to v32. Tried all what you have done with no luck. Finally, installing from github with `npm install https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-native` solved the issue for me. I then installed react-navigation package separately and then all other required modules for my project.

Comment: While you can indeed install the package from github (or any other direct url), this is not the way to solve this, since you are sacrificing access to all the updates and bugfixes (one of the points of package managers).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just wanted to have any solution that works. Lack of knowledge in npm registry was my fault. And I actually tried the solution suggested by @Josiah and it worked. I just could not add a comment to his post since I do not have enough 'reputation' in stackoverflow. I still wonder why some people have that problem and others don't? And why it was a problem with that specific package. I never had this problem before. And another things is that only when I changed my registry to https://registry.npmjs.COM/ it worked. I still don't get it unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Solved by editing root .npmrc file confirming I had:
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/

My issue was related to having "_auth=".

Both npm and yarn now work with react-navigation and 404's I was getting.
Thanks @Munishkin & @Atin Singh

Comment: I personally added a local .npmrc for the RN project, with registry pointing to: http://registry.npmjs.COM/ like @Munishkin said

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the clear idea to what your exact problem is. So, I am assuming that you're not able to use React-navigation with expo.

Try using yarn for the whole process instead of npm.

Use yarn when expo asks to make a new project and then to install react-navigation use-

> yarn add react-navigation

I used navigation yesterday and it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I have been using npm fine for months. * I get same from running yarn Couldn't find package "@react-navigation/native@3.1.4" required by "react-navigation@^3.0.9" on the "npm" registry.

Comment: yarn add react-navigation

error Couldn't find package "@react-navigation/native@3.1.4" required by "react-navigation" on the "npm" registry.

Comment: Try `expo start --clear` and then reinstall react-navigation.

Comment: I am now using yarn - Thumbs up! Though still same problem Couldn't find package "@react-navigation/native@3.1.4" required by "react-navigation" on the "npm" registry. No luck with expo clear and my registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, 'cause I just tried and it fetches `react-navigation` with all dependencies nicely. Actually if you load https://registry.npmjs.org/@react-navigation%2fnative url directly in your browser you should see the corresponding JSON schema. If it gives you 404 you might want to troubleshoot your DNS resolvers.

Comment: I have had success on a secondary macOS environment. Problem is isolated to my global files or https registry.. not exactly sure.. odd